# My custom dialog doesn't appear when set its width

Tags: android, dialog

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainScreenActivity.this);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_ana_ekran_dialog);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.width = width * 90 / 100;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);

dialog.show();
```

This code is in `onOptionsItemSelected` section when i press action bar button my custome dialog doesn't appear.

My custom dialog doesn't appear when i set it's width?

Comment: What is the value of this `params.width`

Comment: screensize(width) * 90/100 ?

Comment: I can see that. What value does come by that piece of code ? Debug the code or print it.

Comment: it says 972 and Im using samsung s4 for debug

Comment: Before compiling that line its -1 after 972

Comment: You are inflating a custom view. Set the layout param for that only. for the width to work, you need to provide a custom style in the dialog constructor

Comment: I solved it by creating costume dialog class and i called it in my main activity. By the way thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the problem this is the way i fix it...

Costume Dialog Class `public class HarcamaKayitDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener`.

Variables

```
Context ctx;
EditText yorum;
EditText harcama;
Button buttonTamamDialog;
Button buttonIptalDialog;
Dialog dialog;
```

Constractor

```
   public HarcamaKayitDialog(Context context){
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.dialog = this;
   }
```

onCreate.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ana_ekran_alert_dialog);
        Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = width * 90 / 100;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        findViews();

    }
```

onClick.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonTamam:

            //transactions

            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonIptal:
            dialog.dismiss();

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

findViews function.

```
private void findViews() {
    yorum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextYorum);
    harcama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextHarcama);
    buttonTamamDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTamam);
    buttonIptalDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIptal);
    buttonTamamDialog.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonIptalDialog.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```